# How to log in to Chrome with Selenium?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, google-account

I am testing a Chrome extension which requires the user to be logged in to use, but I cannot figure out how to login with my test account. I have tried logging in to `accounts.google.com` but this is apparently insufficient; as far as the chrome APIs are concerned there is no authenticated user.

Chrome keeps prompting for login at `chrome://chrome-signin` but because I can't view the html of the page I can't determine what elements to interact with in Selenium to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to login manually once and then use that for automation.
 Try below code , may be it help you:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","<chrome exe path>");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir= <full local path Google Chrome user data default folder>);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://mail.google.com");
```

Login once manually when browser launched.

Then re-run script now it should use previous login.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: It's a shame that it apparently can't be fully automated but the problem does appear fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can still login automatically. The reason is, when opening the page chrome://chrome-signin, the account textbox is automatically focused, so you just need to use keyboards to login without knowing how the html of the page looks like.

Try the code below (you might need to put some sleep in some places to make sure that everything is loaded properly.

```
public void loginToChrome(username, password) {
    driver.get("chrome://chrome-signin");
    var action = new Actions(driver);
    action.sendKeys(username).perform();
    action.sendKeys(keys.ENTER).perform();
    action.sendKeys(password).perform();
    action.sendKeys(keys.ENTER).perform();
}
```

Comment: I get the message that the synchronization has been disabled by the administrator. Is there a way to confirm this "alert"?
Since it is not a typical old one, it can not be confirmed with `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`

Answer (score 0):

First login to gmail on regular chrome browser (NOT the one triggered by selenium driver). Once you login, install the EditTheCookie extension. And on the gmail tab, click this extension icon. It will give option to copy the cookies in json format to clipboard. Paste that into Gmail.data which will be used in below programme.

Once you past, place that Gmail.data file in a avilable location for below programme (you can place anywhere and update the path of that file in below code accordingly).

I've developed this and is a working solution for me since long.

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Date;

import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class LoginUtils {

private static final String GMAIL_LOGIN_URL = 
"https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver = LoginUtils.login(driver, GMAIL_LOGIN_URL, "Gmail.data");
}

public static final WebDriver login(WebDriver driver, String url, String pathOfJsonFileName) {
    Cookies[] data = readJson(pathOfJsonFileName);

    driver.navigate().to(url);

    // Set the expire time of each cookie.
    Date expiryTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000000000);
    for (Cookies cookie : data) {
        Cookie ck = new Cookie(cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue(), cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getPath(),
                expiryTime, Boolean.parseBoolean(cookie.getSecure()), Boolean.parseBoolean(cookie.getHttpOnly()));
        driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
    }
    return driver;
}

private static final Cookies[] readJson(String jsonFileName) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonFileName));
        json = new String(encoded);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Gson().fromJson(json, Cookies[].class);
}
}
```